# Unity Timer goes into negative?

Tags: c#, timer, unity-game-engine

So, I am trying to make a "Merchant" system for my game. After 5 minutes(timer is ticking) Merchant will be available and 2nd timer will start ticking, but the 2nd timer is in -.

```
    void Update()
{
    timeremaining -= Time.deltaTime;
    int minutes = Mathf.FloorToInt(timeremaining / 60F);
    int seconds = Mathf.FloorToInt(timeremaining - minutes * 60);
    string niceTime = string.Format("{0:0}:{1:00}", minutes, seconds);

    howlonghere -= Time.deltaTime;
    int minutes2 = Mathf.FloorToInt(howlonghere / 60F);
    int seconds2 = Mathf.FloorToInt(howlonghere - minutes * 60);
    string niceTime2 = string.Format("{0:0}:{1:00}", minutes, seconds);

    if (timeremaining > 0)
    {
        Merchanthuman.enabled = false;
        Merchanthuman.interactable = false;
        Tiimer.text = "Merchant will be here: " + niceTime;
    }
    else
    {
        Tiimer.text = "Merchant is here for: " + niceTime2;
        Merchanthuman.enabled = true;
        Merchanthuman.interactable = true;
    }
}
```

That "Merchant is here for: " there should start new count down which would be 2nd time. Like the Will be here is 5 minutes & is here for is 2 minutes.

Comment: So, what is the question? What happens? What is supposed to happen?

Comment: Also, it looks like [deltaTime](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html) isn't constant, so of course `timeremaining` can, and probably will, end up being negative.

Comment: That "Merchant is here for: " there should start new count down which would be 2nd time. Like the Will be here is 5 minutes & is here for is 2 minutes.

Comment: So, where do you set `howlonghere`? And it seems you are decreasing `howlonghere` even while `timereamining` is `>0`. So depending on the relative values of those two, when `timeremaining` reaches `<=0`, `howlonghere` could already be negative.

Comment: Yeah, that's my problem. Setting both of these upper,     
public float timeremaining = 5.00f;
    public float howlonghere = 4.00f;

Comment: Note that the tag for Unity game software is `unity3d`.

Comment: Can you please help me out then :)?

Comment: In your second time calculation string, you reference "minutes" and "seconds" instead of "minutes2" and "seconds2" also, in the "seconds2" variable calculation, you reference "minutes" instead of "minutes2"... Is this supposed to be like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's split it up a little:

```
public const float TravelTime = 5.0f;
public const float VisitTime = 4.0f;
public float timeremaining;
public float howlonghere;

//Setup initial timers
void Start()
{
    timeremaining = TravelTime;
    howlonghere = VisitTime;
}

//Check each frame for the scenario
void Update()
{
    if (timeremaining > 0)
    {
        string niceTime = ElapseTravel();
        Merchanthuman.enabled = false;
        Merchanthuman.interactable = false;
        Tiimer.text = "Merchant will be here: " + niceTime;
    }
    else
    {
        string niceTime2 = ElapseVisit();
        Tiimer.text = "Merchant is here for: " + niceTime2;
        Merchanthuman.enabled = true;
        Merchanthuman.interactable = true;
    }
}

//Elapse remaining time when merchant travels
private string ElapseTravel()
{
    timeremaining -= Time.deltaTime;
    int minutes = Mathf.FloorToInt(timeremaining / 60F);
    int seconds = Mathf.FloorToInt(timeremaining - minutes * 60);
    return string.Format("{0:0}:{1:00}", minutes, seconds); 
}

//Elapse stay time when merchant is here
private string ElapseVisit()
{
    howlonghere -= Time.deltaTime;
    int minutes2 = Mathf.FloorToInt(howlonghere / 60F);
    int seconds2 = Mathf.FloorToInt(howlonghere - minutes2 * 60);
    if (howlonghere <= 0)
    {
        timeremaining = TravelTime;
        howlonghere = VisitTime;
    }
    return string.Format("{0:0}:{1:00}", minutes2, seconds2);
}
```

You were decreasing both `timeremaining` and `howlonghere` regardless of the situation. You need to split both scenarios and elapse (decrease) only one of the values depending on the fact that merchant is travelling to location or if he's already here.

Comment: Thanks, but niceTime & niceTime2 doesn't exsit in current context

Comment: Ah, my bad. Should be fine now.

Comment: Btw, after the "Merchant" has finished visiting it should go back to the when merchant visits "again"

Comment: I've update my answer. I hope I've understood you correctly - you want merchant to travel for 5, then visit for 4 and such scenario over and over again?

Answer (score 0):

Unity Timer is not negative. It is your own variable that is going negative.

What actually happening here is you are checking for 5 minutes and executing `timeremaining -= Time.deltaTime;` that will constantly decreasing your `timeremaining` variable.

Second thing is your are decreasing `howlonghere` at the same time by which it is going negative. Because `howlonghere` is less than `timeremaining`.

So when your first timer becomes  `timeremaining <= 0` then your second timer `howlonghere` will become `howlonghere = -3 minutes`. (Assuming that `timeremaining = 5` and `howlonghere = 2` initially).

What you can do if you don't want to change your logic here.

```
void Update()
{
    timeremaining -= Time.deltaTime;
    int minutes = Mathf.FloorToInt(timeremaining / 60F);
    int seconds = Mathf.FloorToInt(timeremaining - minutes * 60);
    string niceTime = string.Format("{0:0}:{1:00}", minutes, seconds);

    if (timeremaining > 0)
    {
        Merchanthuman.enabled = false;
        Merchanthuman.interactable = false;
        Tiimer.text = "Merchant will be here: " + niceTime;
    }
    else {
        howlonghere -= Time.deltaTime;
        int minutes2 = Mathf.FloorToInt(howlonghere / 60F);
        int seconds2 = Mathf.FloorToInt(howlonghere - minutes * 60);
        string niceTime2 = string.Format("{0:0}:{1:00}", minutes, seconds);   

        Tiimer.text = "Merchant is here for: " + niceTime2;
        Merchanthuman.enabled = true;
        Merchanthuman.interactable = true; 
    }

}
```

Obviously you will customize it more accordingly. But it is just to make you clear.